# mongodb connect using php

Tags: php, mongodb

What if password having `@` in mongodb connect
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2:],...]/db
suppose `username='abc'` and `password='abc@123'`
and in php we create mongo db instance like

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://[abc:abc@123@]localhost/abc');
```

then it gives error like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'couldn't get host info for 123@]localhost'

then how to solve this type of problem..

Comment: The square brackets are just indicators of which part of the connection string is optional. You don't actually have to specify them in your connection string. But yes, having the `@` character in your password is an issue for which you need to follow Phil's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1

Pass the credentials via the second argument to the [`Mongo` constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php)

```
$db = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost', array(
    'username' => 'abc',
    'password' => 'abc@123',
    'db'       => 'abc'
));
```

### Option 2

Use the [`MongoDB::authenticate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.authenticate.php) method

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->abc;

$db->authenticate('abc', 'abc@123');
```

Keep in mind...

> There is a major disadvantage to this method: if the connection is dropped and then reconnects, the new connection will not be authenticated. If you use the URI format, the PHP driver will automatically authenticate the user whenever a new connection is made.

## 2014 Update

Instanciating `Mongo` directly is now deprecated. The advice is to use `MongoClient` instead with the same arguments as above. For example

```
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost', [
    'username' => 'abc',
    'password' => 'abc@123',
    'db'       => 'abc'
]);
```

Comment: Can't use it anymore. It's deprecated.

Comment: @Pian0_M4n Thanks. Please note that the original answer is now over two years old

Answer (score 9):

**2019 Update**

I have used php version 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04. This is a detailed info for solving the connectivity issue. (Skip the parts which you have already done)
First I manually installed mongodb and then the mongodb-php driver for it.

1) Installing mongo db. Enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

In order to properly launch Mongdb as a service, ie automatically starting Mongodb when the system starts, follow the following steps:

Create file mongodb.service in /etc/systemd/system/ by entering the command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

Paste the following contents in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb

$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

2) Installing the mongo-php driver:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Also you might receive error: phpize not found. Phpize is a command which is used to create a build environment. This error could appear at the time of installation of any pecl extension. To solve this problem of the phpize command not found, the user has to install the php5-dev package. 
To install it enter the command:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Then in the php.ini file which is in /etc/php/7.0/apache2 directory, add the mongo db extension:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Add the following line in the file:

extension = mongodb.so;

(Just so you know, the exact location of the file mongodb.so is in /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so.)

So the mongo db is installed along with its driver.

3) Now keep in mind that the mongo-php classes have been changed. Most of the available resources in the net give solutions using old classes which is superseded. Below are the links which you can refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

http://zetcode.com/db/mongodbphp/

Here are some commands for basic database operations:

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(); // Driver Object created
```

To insert data into the database:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$doc = ["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID, "data" => $someData, "info" => $someInfo];

$bulk->insert($doc);

$mng->executeBulkWrite('dbName.collectionName', $bulk);
```

For fetching data:

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]); 

$rows = $mng->executeQuery("dbName.collectionName", $query);

foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
         echo "$row->data - $row->info\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **new Mongo();**  can create problems

"Warning: Instanciating this class will emit E_DEPRECATED warning, and turn off acknowledged writes." - php.com

Use MongoClient() insted

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://testUser:testPass@localhost:myportnumber");
```