# MongoClient() object returning 500 Internal error instead of a blank page

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, php-7.2

I have installed `php7.2`, `MongoDB v4.2.8`, relevant driver using `pecl`, updated my `php.ini` file with `extension=mongodb.so` line under `Dynamic Extensions`.

I tried creating a simple HTML web form with three textbox fields as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Insert to MongoDB</h1>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      <input type="text" name="mobile" value="">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="">
      <button type="submit" name="button">Insert</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i click the `Insert` button, ideally these should be snet to MongoDB. I have an `insert.php` file that has a single line to create a new MongoClient object as follows:

```
<?php
      // $mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
      // $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
      $mongo = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://<ec2-public-dns-name>");
      // var_dump($manager);
    ?>
```

I tried `MongoClient()`, `MongoClient(localhost:27017");`, `MongoClient("<ec2-public-DNS-name>:27017");`,  `MongoClient("<ec2-public-IP>:27017");` and `MongoDB\Client("mongodb://<ec2-public-dns-name>");`

Whatever I tried, it returns me a 500 error. If there is no error in the code, it should have idealy returned a **blank page**. If this object was created, then I would have moved to next steps of creating my DB object and then executing `$collection->insert($document)` command.

Comment: I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356834/mongodb-connect-using-php) that the class had changed. Try `new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();`

Comment: Wow. Thank you Parth. It worked like a charm. Saved a lot of my time. +1 to the reply.! :)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for documentation. Please accept that. Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

For php version 7.X, the mongo classes have changed. Refer to the following link for the updated classes.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Create a driver object as:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
```

Insight from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356834/mongodb-connect-using-php) answer.